# Which IP should I use for my nameserver

Tags: nameserver

Sorry to ask whats probably very obvious question. I have just got a new server that is fantastically cheap but unfortunatly doesnt come with any technical support and Im very out of my depth!

My hosting company has provided the following information...

Below you will find your additional IP addresses added to
the server `5.9.xx.xx`

Please note that you can use the subnet only for this server.

```
IP: 5.9.xxx.xx /27
Mask: 255.255.255.224
Broadcast: 5.9.xxx.xx
```

Useable IP addresses:

```
5.9.xxx.xx to 5.9.xxx.xx
```

It has cPanel with WHM and im going through the setup...

I have a number of questions:

My domain is purchased from godaddy and I want to use it as the name server.

- Question 1:

Which IP or IP's do I enter into the godaddy interface for

```
ns1.mydomian.com
ns2.mydomain.com
```

- Question 2:

In the WHM nameserver setup what do I enter for...

```
Please enter an IP address for each of your nameservers.
ns1.mydomain.com ??????     
ns2.mydomain.com ??????

Add "A Entries" for Hostname

IP for Entry: ?????????
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense, do you want to run your own DNS server or do you want godaddy to manage it?

Comment: Vote to close. (a) this is a side for pros, this is a non-pro question. (b) it is way too localized, it is related to ONE particular ISP, ONE version of the panel you use - contact their support. If you signed a contract without, for price, and no w get stuck - maybe you should realize PAYING FOR SUPPORT HAS VALUE.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't make a lot of sense, do you want to run your own DNS server or do you want godaddy to manage it? ns1.mydomain.com should be then the dns server of godaddy.

The A records will then need to point to the IP(s) of your server. For instance domain.com could have ip 5.9.225.65.

This is basic DNS, I suggest you look into the protocol or get someone who knows what he is doing involved.